# AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras' has no attribute '__internal__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf.keras, top2vec

Trying to install top2vec on colab ,and install everything that other people mentioned, but still get this error, have no idea how to solve,anybody knows? really appreciate! [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcCR8.png)

```
!pip install top2vec
!pip install top2vec[sentence_transformers]
!pip install top2vec[sentence_encoders]

from top2vec import Top2Vec
import pandas as pd
```

============================================================
AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras' has no attribute '**internal**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue:

The recent release of Keras 3 breaks TensorFlow Probability at import.

*installation of tensorflow v2.15.0, tensorflow-probability v0.23.0, and keras v3 causes* a

```
AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

---

Please see these posts:

https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1774#issuecomment-1979642276

#### First install `tensorflow-probability` version `0.24.0` then install `tensorflow-keras`

---

https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-7b-it/discussions/71